# Function php with loop

Tags: php

In index.php I have arrays listing folders. Function.php has code that counts the size of the folder. The code works when I type the folder name manually. I don't know how to make the code in function.php count for all folders in index.php. In index.php I made a loop `foreach ($nameFolders as $index => $value) {echo $nameFolders[$index];}` but it does not work in function.php `$disk_used = foldersize ($nameFolders[$index]);`

index.php

```
$nameFolders = array("nameFolder1", "nameFolder2", "nameFolder3");

foreach ($nameFolders as $index => $value) {
    echo $nameFolders[$index];
}

include 'function.php';
```

function.php

```
$units = explode(' ', 'B KB MB GB');
$disk_used = foldersize($nameFolders[$index]);
$totalSize = format_size($disk_used);

function foldersize($path)
{
    $total_size = 0;
    $files = scandir($path);
    $cleanPath = rtrim($path, '/').'/';
    foreach ($files as $t) {
        if ($t <> "." && $t <> "..") {
            $currentFile = $cleanPath.$t;
            if (is_dir($currentFile)) {
                $size = foldersize($currentFile);
                $total_size += $size;
            } else {
                $size = filesize($currentFile);
                $total_size += $size;
            }
        }
    }

    return $total_size;
}

function format_size($size)
{
    global $units;
    $mod = 1024;
    for ($i = 0; $size > $mod; $i++) {
        $size /= $mod;
    }
    $endIndex = strpos($size, ".") + 3;

    return substr($size, 0, $endIndex).' '.$units[$i];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how to go about the loop"? What's your question about this, if the code already works?

Comment: in index.php i have loop `foreach($path_Folder as $index => $value) { echo $path_Folder[$index];}` and  I want use this loop in function.php in `$disk_used = foldersize("../../../$path_Folder[$index]");` but this code doesn't work :(

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing. "It doesnt work" is not a good description of your problem - what have you tried to make it work? What **exactly** is not working?

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing**. Don't use the comment section for relevant stuff

Comment: If your code is literally exactly `("$nameFolders [$index]")` with the space before `[`, that is very likely getting misinterpolated within the quotes. Remove the quotes there because you don't need them in `()` and lose that extra space

Comment: don't look to space, maybe when I wrote post i must mistake. My problem is how use loop `foreach ($nameFolders as $index => $value) ` in function.php

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your code, starting with the `include` order. If you include (and thus declare) the functions AFTER your loop, you cannot use them inside the loop; I understand that you are trying to print all the folders with their sizes.

index.php

```
<?php

include_once('function.php'); // this needs to happen before.

$name_folders = array('nameFolder1', 'nameFolder2', 'nameFolder3');

// no need for key => value here if you don't use that
foreach ($name_folders as $folder) {

    $disk_used = folder_size($folder);
    $totalSize = format_size($disk_used);

    echo "$folder: $totalSize\n";
}
```

function.php

```
<?php

$units = explode(' ', 'B KB MB GB');

function folder_size($path)
{
    $total_size = 0;
    $files = scandir($path);
    $cleanPath = rtrim($path, '/').'/';
    foreach ($files as $t) {
        if ($t <> "." && $t <> "..") {
            $currentFile = $cleanPath.$t;
            if (is_dir($currentFile)) {
                $size = folder_size($currentFile);
                $total_size += $size;
            } else {
                $size = filesize($currentFile);
                $total_size += $size;
            }
        }
    }

    return $total_size;
}

function format_size($size)
{
    global $units;
    $mod = 1024;
    for ($i = 0; $size > $mod; $i++) {
        $size /= $mod;
    }
    $endIndex = strpos($size, ".") + 3;

    return substr($size, 0, $endIndex).' '.$units[$i];
}
```

Please note that this "include function.php" style of PHP is how we did it in 1999, and it's not really a modern practice. Same goes for the use of `global` there. Try sticking to ONE naming convention: you mix camelCase with snake_case.